# Prevent icon at end of <p> to break by itself

Tags: css, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

My problem: My clock icons break off like this on some phone screens
[image: clocks-break-bad]
How it should be: They should take the time value with them and break together like this:
[image: clock-breaks-nicely]

Here's the HTML:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfta78n3/

And just in case it could become relevant, because it makes it difficult to wrap something around just the time and the icon without also wrapping the rest of the date -
I'm generating the part in question like this with Vue 3:

```
{{
  formatDate(
    show.dateExport,
    show.timeStart ? "long" : "short"
  )
}}
<span v-if="show.timeStart">
  <i class="bi-clock-fill" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap anything that shouldn't break in a `<span>` and style it with `white-space: nowrap`

```html
<p class="small m-0 font-monospace" style="">
  Sa., 26. Oct 2030, <span class="nobreak">20:30 <i class="bi-clock-fill"></i></span>
</p>
```

```css
.nobreak {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7opu6jmx/)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by wrapping the time with the span:

```
<td class="align-middle">
    <!--v-if-->
    <p class="small m-0 font-monospace" style="">Sa., 26. Oct 2030, <span class="text-nowrap"> 20:30 <i class="bi-clock-fill"></i></span></p>
</td>
```

And adding the `text-nowrap` from bootstrap to the `span`.